# C# Add resource in a list with same name as text in a textbox (and also how to add it twice or thrice)

Tags: c#, image, resources, addition, probability

I need help to add a resource image in a list of images by using textBox.text as the name of the resource.

Ex:

```
List<Image> deckCards1 = new List<Image>();
if textBox1.text = "Iknowyou"
deckCards1.Add(Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.Iknowyou);
```

But I need the textBox's text to be variable so I can write whatever text (x) in it and the program will use a resource with the name (x). So I don't need the "if" (I'm using 400 images... too long to write for each..).

Other question;
Is it possible to add twice or thrice the same image with same name from resources to a list of images as the second or third image count as different images?

Also, I have another question. If you can help me to get rid of it..

```
Random random = new Random();
pictureBox1.Image = deckCards1[random.Next(0, deckCards1.Count - 1)];
pictureBox2.Image = deckCards1[random.Next(0, deckCards1.Count - 1)];
```

How can I make the image displayed on a pictureBox removed from the list of images (deckCards1 on the context) so I can only get others images on others pictureBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time you post, I'd advise you to make two separate questions.

- I would advise you to use a dictionary
  ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) or
  a `List<string>` containing all the resources you want to test, then
  use the method `List.Contains` (
  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ) to
  check if the string inputted in the `TextBox` is present in the
  `List` / `Dictionary`.
- Instead of using the random value directly, you could do this:

  ```
  Random random = new Random();
  int index = random.Next(0, deckCards1.Count - 1); 
  pictureBox1.Image = deckCards1[index]; 
  deckCards1.RemoveAt(index); 
  //...
  ```

Using the index to first associate the image and then remove it from the List through the `List.RemoveAt` method ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))